# Simple Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript function for our school. Our school is Day 1 and Day 2 based. So far I was using this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = new Date();
  var day = now.getDate();

  if (day % 2 == 0)
   document.write("Day2");
  else
    document.write("Day1");

</script>
```

The only problem is that when we have Pro-D days ( no school on one day ) the days get messed up..

I know what days we don't have school, so any way I can let the function know ?

I dont think there is a specific pattern for the pro-d days. And yes I know what days there are no school.

Here is a link to the calendar. http://south.sd41.bc.ca/admin/calendars/calendar.html

Comment: This is a clear case of incomplete information. UNLESS there is contextual knowhow that e.g. anyone currently enrolled in a US school has, but I'm hard-pressed to guess what you're up to.

Comment: Need more information. What is Pro-D

Comment: You need to put in the rules, basically.  Hopefully there is a pattern to these Pro-D days, otherwise you may need to hard-code in the dates.

Comment: Calculate how many Pro D days have already passed this month, and add that number to `day`. This should be sufficient to create an offset that will get your modulus result back on track.

Comment: @Mörre, Shiplu: *"...we have Pro-D days ( no school on one day )..."* OP needs to offset the no school days to maintain the Day1/2 sequence.

Comment: @James Black please see the updated question.

Comment: Your best bet is to have the calendar in a database, and then just make a REST call for the month, or for the next 7-30 days and display the information.

Answer (score 1):

Even though i dont know what you really trying to do (maybe you should really specify your question), i deliver a solution for the question I understood:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var now = new Date();
 var day = now.getDate();

 var noschool1 = new Date();
 noschool1.setDate(3); //do the same with setyear or whatever you need
 var noSchoolDays = [noschool1]; //add more if you need

 var noschool = false;
 for (d in noSchoolDays) {
    if (now.getDate()==noSchoolDays[d].getDate()
          && now.getMonth()==noSchoolDays[d].getMonth()
          && now.getYear()==noSchoolDays[d].getYear()) {
         noschool = true;
         break;
     }
 }

 if (noschool)
   document.write("no school today");
 else if (day % 2 == 0)
   document.write("Day2");
 else
   document.write("Day1");

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! Just to be more specific, here is a link to our calendar.[link](http://south.sd41.bc.ca/admin/calendars/february.pdf). As you can see on the 23rd it was a day 1 and on the 24th there was no school(doesn't count as a day) and on monday it is a day 2. Also, is there anyway I can make the [noschool1] varible into an array so I can just put the dates in an array? Thanks Again!

Comment: noSchoolDays actually IS an arrray (its just the json format i used).
you can also do 
    noSchoolDays = [noschool1,noschool2,noschool3,noschool4,...]

Comment: Is there any way that I can make [noschool] to count as a day? So if today is day 2, and tomorrow is no school, the day after would be day 1. Currently, the day after would be day 2.

Comment: dont know if you mean that but you could do another variable:

`var noschoolday = null;`


`if (...) noschool=true; noschoolday = noSchoolDays[d]; break;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How would I implement this variable to the code you wrote above? Would I just add another else if ?  if (noschool)
   document.write("no school today");
 else if (day % 2 == 0)
   document.write("Day2");
 else
   document.write("Day1");